# RxJS error in inner stream kill the source

Tags: rxjs

I have the following stream:

```
const source = fromEvent(document.querySelector('h1'), 'click').pipe(
  switchMap(() => {
    return timer(500).pipe(
      switchMap(() => timer(500).pipe(tap(() => {
        throw new Error('error')
      })))
    )
  })
)
```

When the inner stream throws, the `fromEvent` source is also stopped. How can I prevent this and keep the source stream alive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try the following:

```js
const source = fromEvent(document.querySelector('h1'), 'click').pipe(
  switchMap(() => {
    return timer(500).pipe(
      switchMap(() => timer(500).pipe(tap(() => {
        throw new Error('error')
      }))),
      catchError(() => EMPTY)
    )
  })
)
```

where `EMPTY` is nothing but [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/empty.ts#L28):

```js
export const EMPTY = new Observable<never>(subscriber => subscriber.complete());
```

---

The reason this is happens is that when an error occurs, even in a `next` callback(e.g `tap`'s first argument), it will be passed through as:

```js
this.destination.error(caughtError);
```

where `destination` is the next subscriber in the chain(downwards). Eventually `catchError` will be reached and this prevents the error from affecting the *outermost* stream(whose source is `fromEvent`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `retry` operator after the first `switchMap`, like this

```
const source = fromEvent(document.querySelector('h1'), 'click').pipe(
  switchMap(() => {
    return timer(500).pipe(
      switchMap(() => timer(500).pipe(tap(() => {
        throw new Error('error')
      })))
    )
  }),
  retry()
)
```

If no parameter is passed to `retry`, then it will resubscribe to the source observable an infinite amount of times. Otherwise you can pass an integer which represents the number of times it will retry before eventually error.

[Here a stackblitz](https://rxjs-1yjjpm.stackblitz.io).